# How do I make API calls for reading/writing in Blazor c#?

Tags: razor, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I'm looking at lots of sites online about how to make API calls using Swagger:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cqrs-and-mediatr-pattern-implementation-using-net-core-6-web-api/

https://code-maze.com/csharp-mediatr-publish-and-send-methods/

https://code-maze.com/cqrs-mediatr-in-aspnet-core/

Those describe what I am doing for the API side, but no one seems to show how to use these on a Blazor/Razor page.

After I have changed the data, how do I send it back? Can I send and receive a whole class object (like an Employee) or do I have to retrieve it piece by piece (Employee Name, Employee Number, Employee Salary, Employee Hire Date)?

### How do I get the data to the web page?

Comment: APIs generally return JSON-formatted strings.  You send an http/https web request to the API, usually with some kind of query parameter in the URL, and you get back a JSON-formatted string, which you then unpack into a class instance.  The reason maybe nobody shows how to do this is that an API should be accessible from ANY framework or client, so you have to find how to unpack JSON in your client (in this case C#).

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, do you know of any websites that would step through something like this?

Comment: *shhhhh* I recommend asking ChatGPT-- but you didn't hear me say that.  Try: "How can I unpack the results of an API call to a class instance in C#"? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Focusing on retrieving data in a Blazor application from an API structured with CQRS and MediatR patterns involves several steps. Here's a more detailed look at how you can fetch data (like retrieving an `Employee` object) and display it on your Blazor/Razor page:

1. **Implement Methods to Retrieve Data:**

   - In your service class, implement methods to make GET requests to your API and deserialize the response into your model classes.
   - Example:

     ```cs
     public class ApiService
     {
         private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

         public ApiService(HttpClient httpClient)
         {
             _httpClient = httpClient;
         }

         public async Task<Employee> GetEmployeeAsync(int id)
         {
             var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"api/employees/{id}");
             response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
             var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Employee>(responseBody);
         }
     }
     ```
2. **Inject and Use the Service in Blazor Components:**

   - Inject the service into your Blazor components or pages.
   - Use the service methods to fetch data in the component's lifecycle methods like `OnInitializedAsync`.
   - Example:

     ```
     @inject ApiService ApiService

     @code {
         private Employee employee;

         protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
         {
             employee = await ApiService.GetEmployeeAsync(1);
         }
     }
     ```

I left out making the request and API service
as i think you already got this and where only asking for interpreting i coming response.

The whole magic u asking for happens in de-/serialization of the json data. This data holds the complete object as json and can be converted to a object with help of JsonSerializer.

EDIT:
Are you asking about a scenario where you receive an employee object, modify its surname, and then send the updated object back to your API for saving? If that's the case, you would typically use a PUT or POST API call. The choice between PUT and POST depends on the specific requirements and conventions of your API. For a detailed understanding of the differences between PUT and POST, this Stack Overflow post can be helpful: [What is the difference between POST and PUT in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-put-in-http).

In your code, making a POST or PUT call is a bit different from a GET call. You would use the `PostAsync` or `PutAsync` methods of `HttpClient`. Here's how you might do it with a POST request:

**Example Code for POST Method:**

```cs
public async Task AddEmployeeAsync(HttpClient client, Employee employee)
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee);
    var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("employees", data);

    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // Handle the result as needed
}
```

In this revised example, the `HttpClient` and the API's base URL are assumed to be configured and injected externally. The method `AddEmployeeAsync` now accepts an `HttpClient` and an `Employee` object. The `HttpClient` instance is used to send a POST request to the endpoint (in this case, "employees" is appended to the base URL configured in the `HttpClient`). This is a typical approach in environments where dependency injection is used to manage HTTP client instances.

Comment: Close, and no I did not downvote. I hate that feature. After modifying *employee*, how do I submit the changes?

Comment: This might be what I need to do: https://tutorials.eu/how-to-call-post-api-in-csharp/